# Best approach for integrating custom graphics in iOS development

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

What are the best references to read (online resources or books) to read about the approaches and techniques for integrating custom images, graphics, icons for iOS apps? (What are the best strategy to manage custom images for iOS development?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uh, ok, not sure if you need super high level OpenGL graphics performance but if you're making ordinary iPhone apps (not games), then maybe these starter knowledge can guide you.

This is from my own limited experience but there are two types of graphics that I distinguish: graphics that are packaged with the app and graphics that are loaded through some network or file on the device.

For graphics that are packaged with the app, these tend to be the buttons and backgrounds for the look and feel of an app.

With these kind of graphics, to display an image to your application, the general idea is you create a UIImageView then add it as a subview of your View Controller's view. You then tell your image view object the image you want to display.

```
// create the image view object to display the image
UIImageView *myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,100,100)];

// tell the image view object the image you want to display
[myImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"mybutton.png"]];

// add the image view object to your view controller's view
[self.view addSubview:myImageView];

[myImageView release];
```

As for network images, I usually get the URL of the image I want to display, then use a image caching library such as **SDWebImage** to load the image like so:

```
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://www.mysite.com/images/myphoto.png"]; 
[myImageView imageWithURL:urlOfImage placeholder:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]]; 
[url release];
```

How you get the URL path to your image from the network is a different matter though. If you're loading through a web service, you usually have to fetch it from the JSON or XML output.

Comment: Question: is doing it programatically the only way? Can graphics be integrated using the Interface Builder or StoryBoard - without coding? (No, I'm not doing a super-high level OpenGL app.) :-)

Comment: You can certainly drag and drop UIImageView objects using interface builder, but it is usually more for laying out your interface and navigation. There is a limitation to how much you can do with interface builder e.g. if you wanted to slide an entire view across the screen when some data is downloaded from a server, then animate a custom tab bar sliding up and only show certain tabs based on logged in account, then you'll want to know how to do those using programming.